# Spring GCP - OneToMany, ManyToOne, ManyToMany in Google Datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, spring-data, google-cloud-datastore, spring-cloud-gcp

I'm trying to find a way how to implement OneToMany, ManyToOne, ManyToMany relationships in Spring GCP.

According to the reference, there are three ways to represent relationships between entities: embedded, `@Descendant` and `@Reference`. And there is no other way to implement the above annotations.
Please, clarify the way about implementation of JPA annotations.